# How to copy a file to a dynamic string array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, readfile

I'm trying to read in an entire input file into a string.  Right now I have:

```
bool DynString::readLine(std::istream& in)
{
    if(in.eof())
    {
        *this = DynString();    // Default string value.
        return(false);
    }

    char s[1001];
    in.getline(s, 1001);

    // Delete old string-value and create new pBuff string with copy of s
    delete [] pBuff;

    pBuff = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    DynString pBuff(s);

    return(true);
}

bool DynString::readFile(const char filename[])
{
    std::ifstream in(filename);
    if(! in.is_open() )
    {
        *this = DynString();    // Default string value.
        return(false);
    }

    // Delete old string-value and
    // Read the file-contents into a new pBuff string

    delete [] pBuff;

    DynString tempString;
    return(true);
}
```

Where pBuff is a Dynamic String object called DynString

What I think I have to do is create a temporary DynString object and have it serve as a temp, then use the readLine method to assign the temp string to a line of the text file.  once that is done, I would delete the old string array "pBuff" then copy the temp to a new pBuff array.

Would this require the use of a concatonate function, where I would just add the elements in the temp array to the existing pBuff?

Sorry if this is kind of confusing, it has other methods in the header file, but it is all too much to include.

Comment: Are the contents of the file to be stored in pBuff? Maybe providing just the header would help us understand how the class is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something simpler like the following or do you have to use your DynString class?

```
static std::string readFile(const std::string& sFile)
{
  // open file with appropriate flags
  std::ifstream in1(sFile.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
  if (in1.is_open())
  {
    // get length of file:
    in1.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
    std::streamoff length = in1.tellg();
    in1.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
    // Just in case
    assert(length < UINT32_MAX);
    unsigned uiSize = static_cast<unsigned>(length);
    char* szBuffer = new char[uiSize];
    // read data as a block:
    in1.read (szBuffer, length);
    in1.close();

    std::string sFileContent(szBuffer, uiSize);
    delete[] szBuffer;
    return sFileContent;
  }
  else
  {
     // handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to use the DynString class